# Confused as to where is the adjectival phrase in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Which word is modified by the adjectival phrase in the sentence below?

> The savings to the project manager at NASA were substantial.

- A. savings
- B. project
- C. were
- D. NASA

An adjectival phrase usually starts with a preposition or a particle.

Is the adjectival phrase **to the project manager at NASA**?

I think the modified word here is ***savings***. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand that definition of "adjectival phrase".  (Someone else might.)  Do you have a definition from your book?  To me, an "adjective phrase" is a phrase with an adjective as a head.  It can be modified (most commonly by adverbs) or have complements (preposition phrases or subordinate clauses).  So here, I'd have said that "substantial" is the adjective phrase.

Comment: @snailboat Traditional grammar would have treated *to ... NASA* as an adjectival modifying *savings*. Not just any old savings but savings *to the project manager at NASA*. I suppose you could regard it as an indirect object of *save*, but that takes complementation rather farther than I'm comfortable with.

Comment: Based on what I read from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase (under the section "Adjective phrase vs. adjectival phrase"), I think you're right.

Comment: I'm not sure that`The savings to the project manager at NASA were substantial.`is grammatically correct. I think it should be formatted as: `The projects manager at NASA's savings were substantial.` Not dead certain though.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Traditional grammar would have treated “to [. . .] NASA” as an adjectival modifying “savings”. Not just any old savings but savings “to the project manager at NASA”.

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase#Adjective_phrase_vs._adjectival_phrase) for more detail.